# Torch forgets the variable with respect to differentiate

Tags: python, optimization, torch

I am solving an optimization problem on Google Colab via optim from torch. After having applied the gradient step, I have to project the new iterate on the hypercube [0,1]^n, where n is the dimension of the data, but after doing that the automatic differentiation seems to not work anymore. One may find the code below<sup>1</sup>.

```
import torch
from tqdm import tqdm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

device = ("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "mps" if torch.backends.mps.is_available() else "cpu")
print(f"Using {device} device")

dtype = torch.cuda.FloatTensor if device=="cuda" else torch.float64

# Create images
psf = np.zeros((128,128))
psf[63:64,63:64] = 1
gn  = np.random.normal(0,.1,(128,128))
# Scaling psf
psf = psf/psf.sum()
plt.imshow(psf)

gn  = torch.tensor(gn,device=device).type(dtype)
psf = torch.tensor(psf,device=device).type(dtype)
# For the correct dimension for convolution?
psf = psf[None,None,:]
gn  = gn[None,None,:]

### Objective function
def ObjFun(inputX, target, H, dtype, device,beta=1e-3):

  out     = torch.nn.functional.conv2d(inputX,H,padding='same').type(dtype)
  Z       = torch.zeros(inputX.shape).type(dtype).to(device)
  mse     = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum').type(dtype)
  elle1   = torch.nn.L1Loss().type(dtype)

  y = 0.5*mse(out,target)  + beta*0.5*mse(inputX,Z)

  return y

### Projection function
def Proj(inputX):
    y = torch.minimum(torch.maximum(inputX,torch.tensor(0)),torch.tensor(1))
    return y


Y = torch.full(gn.shape,0.5).type(dtype).requires_grad_(True).to(device)

N  = 1000
funobj = np.zeros(N)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD([Y], lr=1e-3)

for step in tqdm(range(N)):
  #optimizer = torch.optim.SGD([Y], lr=1e-3)

  optimizer.zero_grad()
  loss =  ObjFun(Y, gn, psf, dtype, device,beta=1)
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()
  funobj[step] = loss.detach().cpu()
  Y = Proj(Y).clone().detach().requires_grad_(True).to(device).type(dtype)

plt.plot(funobj)
plt.figure()
ax1=plt.imshow(Y.detach().squeeze().cpu())
plt.colorbar(ax1)
```

As one can see, after the first iteration nothing works, in the sense that the objective function is not decreasing and reaches a plateau. Removing the projection the procedure minimizes the objective function and provides a reasonable result.

But if I re-initialize the optimizer each time, removing the comment in the main cycle, everything works fine and I get a reliable and reasonable result.

Is there any way to make the optimizer "remember" wrt *what* it has to optimize after having applied another function to the iterate, without initialising it each step?

---

<sup>1</sup> This is a *oversimplified* version of my algorithm and of my objective function (which is not so nice), but the problem consists in applying the function to the iterate just after the gradient step.